# Determining accretion rate of a cube.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a cube of size $h$, which is 'accreting' at a fixed rate $R$ - i.e. volume ($V$) is added in proportion to the surface area ($A$) of the cube, where $R$ is in units of $\frac{V}{A t}$.

I know the initial size of the cube ($h_0$) and the final size of the cube ($h_1$), and the elapsed time ($t_1$) - how do I calculate $R$?

The system is described by:

$$
\frac{dV}{dt} = R A
$$

Because the structure is a cube, I know that:

$$
V = h^3 \\
A = 6 h^2 = 6 V ^{2/3}
$$

Thus:
$$
\frac{dV}{dt} = R 6 V^{2/3}
$$

And that's where I get stuck... any suggestions very welcome!

In case context makes a difference, I'm trying to estimate the growth rate of a cubic crystal normalised to its surface area (i.e. $mol\ m^{-2}\ s^{-1}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found a solution:

$$
\frac{dV}{dT} = R\ 6 V^{2/3} \\
\frac{1}{6 V^{2/3}} dV = R\ dt \\
\int{\frac{1}{6 V^{2/3}} dV} = \int{R\ dt} \\
\frac{V^{1/3}}{2} + C = R t + C \\
V^{1/3} = 2 R t + C \\
V = (2 R t + C)^3 \\
R = \frac{V^{1/3} - C}{2t}
$$

What is C? We know that when $t = 0$, $V = V_0$, so:
$$
V = (2 R t + C)^3 \\
V_0 = C^3 \\
C = V_0^{1/3}
$$
so:
$$
R = \frac{V^{1/3} - V_0^{1/3}}{2t}
$$